# MySql Query - Multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-concat, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating this MYSQL query:

```
SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '2', value, NULL)) AS 'Field1',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '3', value, NULL)) AS 'Field2',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '4', value, NULL)) AS 'Field3',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '5', value, NULL)) AS 'Field4',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '6', value, NULL)) AS 'Field5',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '7', value, NULL)) AS 'Field6',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '8', value, NULL)) AS 'Field7',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '9', value, NULL)) AS 'Field8'
from wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE form_id = "3"
GROUP BY lead_id;
```

And I get good results for the above query. I have another table which stores the date for each entry and can be crosschecked by the `form_id`.

The query I am using to get the dates is the following:

```
SELECT date_created FROM wp_rg_lead WHERE form_id="3";
```

I need to join both queries so I get all the results in one.

Comment: does your second query returns just 1 record for the `form_id=3` ?

Comment: @Alex it returns all the dates for each submission I have. So if for example the first query returns three rows of data, then the second query returns three rows of dates

Comment: does your second table have column `lead_id` ?

Comment: @Alex nope it does not.

Comment: so on which column do you plan to join tables then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide tables structure, here is my guess:

```
SELECT
      wp2.date_created,
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '2', value, NULL)) AS 'Field1',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '3', value, NULL)) AS 'Field2',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '4', value, NULL)) AS 'Field3',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '5', value, NULL)) AS 'Field4',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '6', value, NULL)) AS 'Field5',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '7', value, NULL)) AS 'Field6',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '8', value, NULL)) AS 'Field7',
      GROUP_CONCAT(if(field_number = '9', value, NULL)) AS 'Field8'
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail wp1
LEFT JOIN wp_rg_lead wp2
ON wp1.lead_id = wp2.id
WHERE wp1.form_id = "3"
GROUP BY wp1.lead_id;
```